# Count Data from Excel when one cell had array data

Tags: excel

I have some data in excel and i want to count of data, as simple as that..
I'm using countif/countifs but return number was wrong..

I want to return count of data from B3:B10 and the criteria is C3

Here's data :[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdrqb.jpg)

Comment: **unclear** Do you want a count of the **cells** that contain the data or a count of the **times the data occurs** ??

Comment: It would help if you told us what the expected output is and **why**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of **cells** that contain at least one instance of `111111` use:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B10,"*" & C3 & "*")
```

To count the number of **times** `111111` occurs, use:

```
  =(LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(B3:B10," ","")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(B3:B10," ","")),C3,"")))/LEN(C3)
```

[image]

Comment: yes this is the answer i'm looking for,,to count number of times exactly..